# Excel SUMIFS over a range of number formatted as text

Tags: excel, formatting, sumifs

I am currently working on an Excel Sheet with thousands of entries.

In one of the columns all the numbers are stored as text. I want to make a `SUMIFS` over those entries, but it does not seem no work because of the wrong formatting. Is there any way to calculate my results without changing the original data?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean without formatting the cells to general or numbers?

Comment: Yes exactly. The original data should not be touched at all. This also seems not to work: `SUMIFS(VALUE(MyRange);condrange1;cond1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this as an array formula (press `ctrl` + `shft` + `enter`):

```
=SUM(IF(B1:B5="d",NUMBERVALUE(A1:A5)))
```

Or, as a regular formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B1:B5="d")*(C1:C5="g"),NUMBERVALUE(A1:A5))
```